# Click back button to show toast notification and on click again it should exit the app

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, toast, back-button

I'm creating my cordova app where on clicking default back button in mobile app it should show a toaster notification that "Tap again to exit the app", then on clicking back button again it should exit the app.

I tried some codes but none of the code seems to work in the app.

```
window.plugins.toast.showWithOptions(
    {
      message: "Tap again to exit the app",
      duration: 1500, // ms
      position: "bottom",
      addPixelsY: -40,  // (optional) added a negative value to move it up a bit (default 0)
      data: {'foo':'bar'} // (optional) pass in a JSON object here (it will be sent back in the success callback below)
    },
    // implement the success callback
    function(result) {
      if (result && result.event) {
        console.log("The toast was tapped or got hidden, see the value of result.event");
        console.log("Event: " + result.event); // "touch" when the toast was touched by the user or "hide" when the toast geot hidden
        console.log("Message: " + result.message); // will be equal to the message you passed in
        console.log("data.foo: " + result.data.foo); // .. retrieve passed in data here

        if (result.event === 'hide') {
          console.log("The toast has been shown");
        }
      }
    }
  );
```

Expected Result : on clicking default back button in mobile app it should show a toaster notification that "`Tap again to exit the app`", then on clicking back button again it should exit the app.
Actual Result : *It does not show any toast notification message.*

Answer (score 0):

You can create your logic like this:

```js
int isTouched = false;

public void btnClick(View view){

  if(isButtonTouched)//exit 
  else isButtonTouched=true(and show your toast)

}
```